# How to resolve database connection string problems in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

I am developing an asp.net mvc3 application using Visual Studio 2010.I need to access the database.
I wrote the connection string as

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=./App_Data/Abcd.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

But, when I run the code, I get an error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server.

From the SQL Server Configuration Manager, I enabled TCP/IP but I still get the same exception.

I also tried changing the connection string to

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString");
```

But I got an exception that said "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

How do I overcome this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using SQL Developer/Standard, or SQL Express? Can you connect using SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on the type of database you are using: SQL Express or SQL Developer/Standard. If you use SQL Express you may take a look at the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247257.aspx) illustrating different connection strings. For example:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|Abcd.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

If you are using the full version of SQL Server, your database is no longer stored in the App_Data folder. It is managed by SQL Server. Checkout the [following site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) for connection strings in this case depending on your scenario.

Example:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;database=dbname;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Abcd.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
or
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("webconfigconnectionname").ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

In VS click on server explorer and add the connection
when the connection has been setup right click on the established connection and select properties 
you will get the properties window open. In that window select the connection string, which you can use in the sqlconnection